# Is there ever a need for a temporary object on the callers stack frame?

Tags: c++

Without optimizations from the compiler, upon assignment the following constructors are called (code below):

- Constructor (inside function)
- Move Constructor (moving to an reserved location on the callers stack?)
- Move Constructor (caller moves from reserved location to the destination on the callers stack)

I know that Return Value Optimization can always be applied, while it depends on the program flow for NRVO. However, there seems to be one optimization applied in both cases (removing the need for the first move and directly move to the destination).

Example:

```
struct Data { 
  char bytes[1600]; 
};

Data f() {
  Data result = {};
  return result;
}

int main() {
  Data d = f();
}
```

With no optimizations (-fno-elide-constructors) [takes 2 times the space on the callers stack frame]:

```
main:
  push rbp
  mov rbp, rsp
  sub rsp, 3200

f():
  push rbp
  mov rbp, rsp
  sub rsp, 1616
```

With elide:

```
main:
  push rbp
  mov rbp, rsp
  sub rsp, 1600
```

My question is: Is there any situation where it is required to have 2 moves / the "hidden" temperory object on the callers stack? If NRVO or RVO can be applied there is no move, if it isn't possible than there is 1 move with optimizations (directly to the location of the left hand side operator).

It seems like the hidden temporary object on the callers stack is just a waste of space and an additional move that can always be prevented, since the caller already knows where the result should be moved to. It can always construct the corresponding data in the function, and copy/move it to the location on the left hand side of the assignment. No need for construction=copy=>hidden object=copy>left hand side of assigment.

Comment: I don't get the question.  Are you asking why they don't optimize unoptimized code?

Comment: At its simplest, there has to be a place for the return value because the caller might not use it. Instead of `Data d = f():` try `f();`; the function returns a value, so there has to be a place to put it, even though it isn't used.

Comment: Well more like the reason from the compiler. It's like putting every value two times on the Stack. That wouldnt make sense but could also be optimized.

Comment: @PeteBecker i think that might make sense. Even though i would think it just wouldnt perform the last move as default behavior when no Location is passed by the caller